# Calcular raiz quadrada com dado vindo de texto digitado

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, matemática

Não estou conseguindo fazer a calculadora tirar a raiz de um numero que o usuário digitar. O máximo que consegui foi isso que esta no código, só que independente do valor da tela, ele só retorna o valor da raiz de 2 (1,412...) ou raiz de qualquer valor pré-definido no código. Quero que o programa tire a raiz do valor que tiver na tela.

```
private void buttonRaiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        double label1 = 2;          

        double resutado = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(label1));

        Tela.Text = resutado.ToString();

    }
```

`Tela.Text` é o nome da tela da calculadora. `label1.Text` é o nome de uma *label* que uso na tela da calculadora pra armazenar os números. eu só consigo por `label1`, se por `label1.Text` da erro de tipos de variáveis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você primeiro precisa converter e depois aplicar a operação no número. Mas na forma que está fazendo ainda pode quebrar a aplicação se algo errado for digitado, então o correto é fazer assim:

```
private void buttonRaiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (!double.TryParse(label1, out var valor) //faz alguma coisa aqui para indicar erro
    Tela.Text = Math.Sqrt(valor).ToString();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/SquareRoot.cs).